# Sequence of real analytic functions $f_{n}(x):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly to absolute value function $f(x)=|x|$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, approximation, uniform-convergence

> Construct a sequence of functions $f_{n}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that each $f_{n}$ is real analytic, and moreover $f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=|x|$ on $\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 1):

**Try**:

$f_n(x)=\sqrt {x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the uniform limit of these real analytic functions is not analytic.This never happens with
complex analytic functions.
we have $|x|=\ x \ sgn(x)$ where $\ sgn(x)$ is the sign function

> The sequence $(x \tanh(n x))_n$ converges uniformly to $\ sgn(x)$ on every >bounded interval.If you want it uniform on all of $\ \mathbb{R}$ multiply by $\ (1+x^2)^{-1}$.`see 1.`

I don't know ho to prove the previous fact. Also in an answer to another question posted here 
`see 2.`

> it says that if we have equicontinuity then we can apply Arzelà–Ascoli theorem we can find a homeomorphism $\phi : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^{\ast}$ 
>   such that $f_n \circ \phi$ s equicontinuous. Then we >can apply AA to $(f_n \circ \phi)$ to obtain a uniformly convergent subsequence $(f_n \circ \phi)$. Now it is clear that $f_n \circ \phi$ itself is also uniformly convergent.`see 2.`

```
1. @MISC {1121184,
TITLE = {A uniformly convergent sequence of real analytic functions which does not converge to a real analytic function},
AUTHOR = {quid (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/85306/quid)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
NOTE = {URL:http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1121184 (version: 2015-01-27)},
EPRINT = {http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1121184},
URL = {http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1121184}}

2. @MISC {158098,
TITLE = {Subsequence Convergence},
AUTHOR = {Sangchul Lee (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
NOTE = {URL:http://math.stackexchange.com/q/158098 (version: 2012-06-14)},
EPRINT = {http://math.stackexchange.com/q/158098},
URL = {http://math.stackexchange.com/q/158098}}
```